# Why MongoDB index size is different between servers

Tags: mongodb

*emphasized text*I imported essentially the same dataset into two different MongoDB instances, both running the same version (5.0.24). One is a single node, and the other is a replica set managed by a cloud provider.

When I compare the sizes of both databases, there is a discrepancy due exclusively to the index size. The index from the cloud-managed database is significantly larger. What could be influencing this difference?

On local single instance node, index size is ~21GB:

```
> db.stats(1024 * 1024);

{
  db: 'xxxx',
  collections: 17,
  views: 0,
  objects: 590502520,
  avgObjSize: 3856.4778189430926,
  dataSize: 2171764.250192642,
  storageSize: 260034.8125,
  indexes: 65,
  indexSize: 20994.91015625,
  totalSize: 281029.72265625,
  scaleFactor: 1048576,
  fsUsedSize: 9600854.74609375,
  fsTotalSize: 10984287.98046875,
  ok: 1
}
```

On replicaset managed database from cloud, index size is ~44GB:

```
{
  db: 'xxxx',
  collections: 17,
  views: 0,
  objects: 596353154,
  avgObjSize: 3880.8902943607136,
  dataSize: 2207165.8776950836,
  storageSize: 269442.23046875,
  indexes: 65,
  indexSize: 44406.3515625,
  totalSize: 313848.58203125,
  scaleFactor: 1048576,
  fsUsedSize: 462518.69921875,
  fsTotalSize: 593613.01171875,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1707255303, i: 758 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64("wvvT6KAesYNFw19TxpvjQUXBx+4=", 0),
      keyId: Long("7324449712621223941")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1707255303, i: 758 })
}
```

When I look at index detail cache from a specific index that is way larger on cloud instance (71MB vs 182MB), I can see a lot of difference between the local single instance and cloud instance:

```
> db.myCollection.stats({indexDetails:true, indexDetailsName: 'xxx'}).indexDetails.xxx.cache;
```

On local single instance node:

```
{
  'bytes currently in the cache': 1742,
  'bytes dirty in the cache cumulative': 0,
  'bytes read into cache': 661,
  'bytes written from cache': 0,
  'checkpoint blocked page eviction': 0,
  'checkpoint of history store file blocked non-history store page eviction': 0,
  'data source pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting an out of order on disk value behind the last update on the chain': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting an out of order tombstone ahead of the selected on disk update': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting an out of order tombstone ahead of the selected on disk update after validating the update chain': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting out of order timestamps on the update chain after the selected on disk update': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to needing to remove a record from the history store but checkpoint is running': 0,
  'eviction walk passes of a file': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 0-9': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 10-31': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 128 and higher': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 32-63': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 64-128': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages reduced due to history store cache pressure': 0,
  'eviction walks abandoned': 0,
  'eviction walks gave up because they restarted their walk twice': 0,
  'eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found no candidates': 0,
  'eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found too few candidates': 0,
  'eviction walks reached end of tree': 0,
  'eviction walks restarted': 0,
  'eviction walks started from root of tree': 0,
  'eviction walks started from saved location in tree': 0,
  'hazard pointer blocked page eviction': 0,
  'history store table insert calls': 0,
  'history store table insert calls that returned restart': 0,
  'history store table out-of-order resolved updates that lose their durable timestamp': 0,
  'history store table out-of-order updates that were fixed up by reinserting with the fixed timestamp': 0,
  'history store table reads': 0,
  'history store table reads missed': 0,
  'history store table reads requiring squashed modifies': 0,
  'history store table truncation by rollback to stable to remove an unstable update': 0,
  'history store table truncation by rollback to stable to remove an update': 0,
  'history store table truncation to remove an update': 0,
  'history store table truncation to remove range of updates due to key being removed from the data page during reconciliation': 0,
  'history store table truncation to remove range of updates due to out-of-order timestamp update on data page': 0,
  'history store table writes requiring squashed modifies': 0,
  'in-memory page passed criteria to be split': 0,
  'in-memory page splits': 0,
  'internal pages evicted': 0,
  'internal pages split during eviction': 0,
  'leaf pages split during eviction': 0,
  'modified pages evicted': 0,
  'overflow pages read into cache': 0,
  'page split during eviction deepened the tree': 0,
  'page written requiring history store records': 0,
  'pages read into cache': 1,
  'pages read into cache after truncate': 0,
  'pages read into cache after truncate in prepare state': 0,
  'pages requested from the cache': 0,
  'pages seen by eviction walk': 0,
  'pages written from cache': 0,
  'pages written requiring in-memory restoration': 0,
  'the number of times full update inserted to history store': 0,
  'the number of times reverse modify inserted to history store': 0,
  'tracked dirty bytes in the cache': 0,
  'unmodified pages evicted': 0
}
```

On cloud instance:

```
{
  'bytes currently in the cache': 16222,
  'bytes dirty in the cache cumulative': 31577447,
  'bytes read into cache': 98960667,
  'bytes written from cache': 13993066,
  'checkpoint blocked page eviction': 0,
  'checkpoint of history store file blocked non-history store page eviction': 0,
  'data source pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted': 14,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting an out of order on disk value behind the last update on the chain': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting an out of order tombstone ahead of the selected on disk update': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting an out of order tombstone ahead of the selected on disk update after validating the update chain': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to detecting out of order timestamps on the update chain after the selected on disk update': 0,
  'eviction gave up due to needing to remove a record from the history store but checkpoint is running': 0,
  'eviction walk passes of a file': 129817,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 0-9': 126113,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 10-31': 3704,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 128 and higher': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 32-63': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages histogram - 64-128': 0,
  'eviction walk target pages reduced due to history store cache pressure': 0,
  'eviction walks abandoned': 222,
  'eviction walks gave up because they restarted their walk twice': 128180,
  'eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found no candidates': 0,
  'eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found too few candidates': 0,
  'eviction walks reached end of tree': 257975,
  'eviction walks restarted': 0,
  'eviction walks started from root of tree': 128797,
  'eviction walks started from saved location in tree': 1020,
  'hazard pointer blocked page eviction': 8,
  'history store table insert calls': 0,
  'history store table insert calls that returned restart': 0,
  'history store table out-of-order resolved updates that lose their durable timestamp': 0,
  'history store table out-of-order updates that were fixed up by reinserting with the fixed timestamp': 0,
  'history store table reads': 0,
  'history store table reads missed': 0,
  'history store table reads requiring squashed modifies': 0,
  'history store table truncation by rollback to stable to remove an unstable update': 0,
  'history store table truncation by rollback to stable to remove an update': 0,
  'history store table truncation to remove an update': 0,
  'history store table truncation to remove range of updates due to key being removed from the data page during reconciliation': 0,
  'history store table truncation to remove range of updates due to out-of-order timestamp update on data page': 0,
  'history store table writes requiring squashed modifies': 0,
  'in-memory page passed criteria to be split': 0,
  'in-memory page splits': 0,
  'internal pages evicted': 3319,
  'internal pages split during eviction': 0,
  'leaf pages split during eviction': 150,
  'modified pages evicted': 1001,
  'overflow pages read into cache': 0,
  'page split during eviction deepened the tree': 0,
  'page written requiring history store records': 0,
  'pages read into cache': 9268,
  'pages read into cache after truncate': 0,
  'pages read into cache after truncate in prepare state': 0,
  'pages requested from the cache': 267909,
  'pages seen by eviction walk': 194127,
  'pages written from cache': 1337,
  'pages written requiring in-memory restoration': 823,
  'the number of times full update inserted to history store': 0,
  'the number of times reverse modify inserted to history store': 0,
  'tracked dirty bytes in the cache': 0,
  'unmodified pages evicted': 9224
}
```

Can this explain the size difference between those two index ?

Comment: Are all of the indexes defined exactly the same in both cases?

Comment: Yes, initial database setup and index creation are exactly the same. Index are created via my Spring application and mongo java driver.

Comment: Are you sure the database design is the same and data is at least very similar? You have a difference of around 6 Million documents and have a look at the huge difference on `fsUsedSize/fsTotalSize`

Comment: Did you compare the indexes one by one? Try this: `db.getCollectionInfos({ type: 'collection' }).filter(x => !['system.views'].includes(x.name)).map(x => { return { [x.name]: db.getCollection(x.name).stats(1024 * 1002).indexSizes } })`

Comment: Did the disk have the same cluster lenght when formating ?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit. We have slightly more documents in our managed database because the environment is live. However, it's only about 1% more and does not explain the significant difference in size between the indexes (21GB vs. 44GB).
Thank you for your second response. A few of the documents are very similar, but most of them are larger in the cloud instance, and sometimes by a considerable margin (more than twice as big).

Comment: @SQLpro I'll take a look at it

Comment: Could it be a different WiredTiger configuration?